# Reduce a List of Map of Tuples

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have the following variable

```
val x1 =  List((List(('a',1), ('e',1), ('t',1)),"eat"), (List(('a',1), ('e',1), ('t',1)),"ate"))
```

I want to get a

```
List(Map -> List)
```

that will look something like the following. The idea is to group words b the characters contained in them

```
Map(List((a,1), (e,1), (t,1)) -> List(eat, ate))
```

I have used the following to achieve this however not quite getting it right. I have used the following code and get the expected result

```
scala> val z1 = x1.groupBy(x => x._1 )
                  .map(x => Map(x._1 -> x._2.map(z=>z._2)))
                  .fold(){(a,b) => b}
z1: Any = Map(List((a,1), (e,1), (t,1)) -> List(eat, ate))
```

However, I would like to return the obvious type `Map[List[(Char, Int)],List[String]]` and not `Any` as is returned in my case. Also, i'm wondering if there is a better of doing the whole thing itself. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
scala> x1.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[List[(Char, Int)],List[String]] = Map(List((a,1), (e,1), (t,1)) -> List(eat, ate))
```

But, yeah, I think you might want to reconsider your data representation. That `List[(List[(Char,Int)], String)]` business is rather cumbersome.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm! About that data representation, `List[(List[(Char,Int)], String)]` is computed from a dictionary of different words.

Comment: You could use the following canonicalisation:

    `val words = List("eat", "ate", "cheap", "peach", "tree")
    words.map(w => (w.toLowerCase.sorted, w)).groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map

(_._2))`
This gives:

 `Map(aet -> List(eat, ate), acehp -> List(cheap, peach), eert -> List(tree))`